# How to have multiple files in tabs in Xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode6

in the past (older version of xcode) I had a plus sign in the top right of an editor to add a tab. Then in the new tab I could click on the second file and I had 2 files open in 2 tabs.
My plus sign is gone (I guess with my last update).

How to rollback this + button or how to have tabbed editors in Xcode 6.4 (6E35b) ?

Answer (score 39):

You can show the tab bar (with the + button you mention) from the View menu:

[image: Xcode View menu]

Alternatively you can press CMD+T to open a new tab, which will automatically show the tab bar.

Answer (score 4):

File -> New -> Tab and the + sign will appear

Answer (score 2):

You can use -- `Command + T` or you can follow this also

[image]